# How to make a xmlhttprequest and onload function within another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that makes `xmlhttprequest` to get and parse a JSON. For every value obtained from the JSON, the script makes another `xmlhttprequest` within the forEach loop of previous JSON and tried to append HTML from the data obtained from second JSON.

My script:

```
var request; 
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //make request to post-list file
request.open('GET', 'main.json', true); //post-list file is in base folder
request.onload = function () {
    var dat;
    dat = JSON.parse(request.responseText); //parse the post-list json
    dat.forEach(function (data) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); //make new request for post-detail file
        req.open('GET', data.postid + '.json', true); //path to post-detail file is acquired from post-list file
        req.onload = function () {
            info = JSON.parse(req.responseText); //parse the post-detail file
            // function for page contents
            document.getElementsByClassName('main-content')[0].innerHTML += '<div class="post"><h2><a href="/post.html?id=' + info.postid + '">' + info.title + '</a></h2><p>' + info.excerpt + '...</p></div>';
        };
    });
};
request.send();
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.json:

```
[
    {
       "postid": "2",
       "author": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "postid": "1",
        "author": "John Doe"
    }
]
```

My 1.json: (requested as data.postid.json):

```
{
  "postid": "1",
  "author": "Jhon Doe",
  "title": "This is the first title.",
  "category": [
      "Music",
      "Lifestyle"
  ],
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "Jan",
  "date": "24",
  "text": "<p>This is post 1 full text.</p><p>This is the second paragraph.</p>",
  "excerpt": ""
}
```

Implementation: http://embed.plnkr.co/B9v5OZK7yAQykmRStECA/

My results: only the commands outside of second onload are executed. I can't check if second JSON was successfully parsed.

I would be glad if I could do do this without jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `req.send()` inside the `forEach` loop. If you do not call it, the HTTP call is never made.

I also added the `event` argument to the two `onload` invocations and used `event.target.responseText` variable to get the response to parse

```
var request; 
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open('GET', 'main.json', true); 
request.onload = function (event) { // <-- Add event argument 
    var dat;
    dat = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText); // <-- and use event.target to get the response text
    dat.forEach(function (data) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        req.open('GET', data.postid + '.json', true);
        req.onload = function (event) { // <-- Add event argument 
            info = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText); // <-- and use event.target to get the response text
            var cat = info.category;
            var catl = cat.length;
            var ti = '';
            for (i = 0; i < catl; i++) {
                ti += '<a href="category.html?id=' + cat[i].replace(" ", "-") + '">' + cat[i] + '</a>';
                if (i < catl - 1) {
                    ti += ', ';
                }
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName('main-content')[0].innerHTML += '<div class="post"><h2><a href="/post.html?id=' + info.postid + '">' + info.title + '</a></h2><p>' + info.excerpt + '...</p><div class="meta"><a href="/author.html?id=' + info.author.replace(" ", "-") + '">' + info.author + '</a> in ' + ti + ' <i class="link-spacer"></i> ' + info.month + ' ' + info.date + ', ' + info.year + ' <i class="link-spacer"></i> <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> ' + info.time + ' min read </div></div>';
        };
        req.send(); // <-- You need to send every inner request, otherwise the HTTP call is never made
    });
};
request.send();
```

Please, see the working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Alewp8nW9aPjlbO0DDi1

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be returning the same post twice instead of 2 different posts. Gotta diagnose this further.

https://embed.plnkr.co/qOvlq6MRfu5J4yM1fao5/

Comment: I updated the Plunker code and the response above to fix the problem. I use the `event` argument of `onload` function. If the answer is ok for you, please approve it :)

Comment: yea, its seems to be working. This is the approved answer.